# Combine two SQL

Tags: php, sql

i want to combine the following SQL queries. 
Right now i call them twice, but i think i can handle it in ones. 
I tried but can't find the solution. Can anybody provide me the combined SQL. I know i use MSQL instead of MISQLI or PDO.

```
$lsel_first = mysql_query("select * from table_test WHERE owner = '$id' AND ownersecond = '0' AND catogory = '1' AND type = '$car[id]' AND caseB = '0' AND (timeback < TIMESTAMP(NOW()) OR timeback = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') ");
$first = mysql_num_rows($lsel_first);


$lsel_second = mysql_query("select * from table_test WHERE ownersecond = '$id' AND catogory = '1' AND type = '$car[id]' AND caseB = '0' AND (timeback < TIMESTAMP(NOW()) OR timeback = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')  ");
$second = mysql_num_rows($lsel_second);
```

Comment: You want to essentially get one result set for both queries by doing only one? You can copy the `WHERE` bit of the second, bracket them off and put an `OR` between them. Or you can do a `UNION`.

Comment: Use a UNION you combine multiple queries, to produce one result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
mysql_query("select * from table_test 
WHERE ((owner = '$id' AND ownersecond = '0') OR ownersecond = '$id') 
AND catogory = '1' AND type = '$car[id]' AND caseB = '0' 
AND (timeback < TIMESTAMP(NOW()) OR timeback = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use union

```
select * from table_test WHERE ownersecond = '$id' AND catogory = '1'  
AND type = '$car[id]' AND caseB = '0' AND (timeback < TIMESTAMP(NOW())  
OR timeback = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') union select * from table_test  
WHERE ownersecond = '$id' AND catogory = '1' AND type = '$car[id]'  
AND caseB = '0' AND (timeback < TIMESTAMP(NOW())  
OR timeback = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```